# Liferay elasticsearch request [/liferay-abc20099] contains unrecognized parameter: [include_type_name] status 400

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, liferay, liferay-7

We have liferay installed on azure vm.

Today we have provisioned azure elasticsearch managed service.

We have configured azure elasticsearch in liferay VM with authentication. Now when we click on "Reindex All" on liferay portal it shows success, however in the catalina logs shows exception:

```
Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [PUT], host [https://123456789.region.azure.elastic-cloud.com], URI [/liferay-abc20099?master_timeout=30s&include_type_name=true&timeout=30s], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/liferay-abc20099] contains unrecognized parameter: [include_type_name]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/liferay-abc20099] contains unrecognized parameter: [include_type_name]"},"status":400}
```

Elasticsearch version on lifeary is 7.14.1
Microsoft elasticsearch has version 8.3.3

Kindly advise to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: You said: "Elasticsearch version on lifeary is 7.14.1 Microsoft elasticsearch has version 8.3.3" but Liferay doesn't work with Elsaticsearch 8.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> Elasticsearch version on lifeary is 7.14.1 Microsoft elasticsearch has version 8.3.3"

but Liferay doesn't work with Elasticsearch 8.3.3.
Try using the supported 7.x Elasticsearch version, see https://help.liferay.com/hc/es/articles/360016511651-Search-Engine-Compatibility-Matrix to get the exact version

Comment: ok thanks, will try to make this version compatibility and see if that helps.

Comment: I had installed elasticsearch on VM with exac same version as the liferay and after that its started working. Thanks.